# clang: do friend functions not have spelling attribute?

Tags: python, c++, clang, operator-overloading

I want to use the clang `Cursor` class to get the `spelling` attribute of the operator function for `Timer` from python, but it won't work for a friend function.

Given the C++ class `Timer` in `Timer.hpp`:

```cpp
class Timer {
public:
    // friend operator overload to add minutes to the timer
    friend Timer operator+=(Timer t, int add_mins) {
        // add
        return t;
    }
};

// different operator overload as a non-member non-friend function
bool operator==(Timer t0, Timer t1) {
    return false;
}
```

Here is the python code to get the `spelling` attribute:

```py
from clang import cindex
def print_node(node):
    if len(node.spelling) > 0:
        print("Spelling for node of kind %s: %s" % (node.kind, node.spelling))
    else:
        print("Node of kind %s has no spelling" % node.kind)

index = cindex.Index(cindex.conf.lib.clang_createIndex(False, True))
tu = index.parse('Timer.hpp')
file_node = tu.cursor
for node in file_node.get_children():
    print_node(node)
    if node.kind is cindex.CursorKind.CLASS_DECL:
        for child in node.get_children():
            print_node(child)

        print("Node of kind %s has no spelling" % child.kind)
```

The output of the python code is:

```sh
Spelling for node of kind CursorKind.CLASS_DECL: Timer
Node of kind CursorKind.CXX_ACCESS_SPEC_DECL has no spelling
Node of kind CursorKind.FRIEND_DECL has no spelling
Spelling for node of kind CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL: operator==
```

Notice that the `==` operator has `spelling`, but the friend `+=` operator doesn't. Why is this, and is it possible to get the spelling for the friend function?

Comment: This non-member friend operator+ is always inline. Perhaps inline functions do not have spellings.

Comment: Well that is annoying if so